# How don't override ssh configs when restore filesystem other server?

Tags: ssh

I backup all files from first server and restore it in second server. But now I can't enter to my second server, because ssh configs overrode from first server. What files and directories I need to exclude from backup to restore files and enter in my second server with previous login and passwords? 
`/etc/ssh`, what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, `/etc/ssh` will contain the config and host keys (but a change in host keys will usually "only" give you the annoying fingerprint warning again);

- you probably also want all users' `~/.ssh` directories, in particular `authorized_keys` if you use public/private keypair authentication;
- if you use password authentication (and don't have centralized auth like LDAP, Kerberos, etc.), you need to consider `/etc/shadow`, which contains the password hashes for every user.

Comment: Yes, I use password authentication. Do I understand correctly that I can not add this file to an exclusion, because other users will not be created during the restore (mysql for example). Then I have to manually create users, right?